# pygame help error message "pygame.error: Text has zero width"

Tags: python, pygame

Okay so this is my code and the error I am getting is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0vZC.png)

[image]

and am wondering if you can see any problems with my code. It has something to do with pygame quitting before the game as quit. Thanks, Alex.
The code has other external things but you just need to have a look through it if u can.

```py
import pygame 
import random 
import time 
pygame.init() 
pygame.font.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
width = 1920 
height = 1080
black = (0,0,0) 
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0) 
green = (0,255,0)
light_blue = (0,0,255)
blue = (0,0,200) 
grey = (200,200,200)
dark_grey = (220,220,220)
greenBlue = (25,252,180)
menucolours = (0,0,255)
rollover_greenBlue = (190,50,200)
rollover_menucolours = (190,50,200)
buttonSound = pygame.mixer.Sound("button_click_s.wav")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
background = pygame.image.load('background.jpg')
window = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
window.blit(background, (0,0))
pygame.display.update()


font =  pygame.font.Font('FFFFORWA.TTF',20) 
smallText =  pygame.font.Font('FFFFORWA.TTF',20) 


win = pygame.display.set_mode((1920,1080))
outline=True
def text_objects(text, font, colour = None):
    if colour == None:
        textSurf = font.render(text, True, black)
    else:
        textSurf = font.render(text, True, colour)
    return textSurf, textSurf.get_rect()
def button(x,y,width,height,ac,ic,msg, act=None, msgColour=None, font = None): 
    global List 
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos() 
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed() 
    if x+width > mouse[0] > x and y+height > mouse[1] > y: 
        pygame.draw.rect(window, ac, (x,y,width,height))
        if click[0] == 1 and act != None: 
            buttonSound.play()
            if act == 'rule': 
                function.rules()
            elif act == 'new':
                function.game()
            elif act == 'end':
                function.end() 
            elif act == 'menu':
                function.menu()
            elif act == 'play1':
                List = 0 
                function.place()
            elif act == 'play2':
                List = 1 
                function.place()
            elif act == 'play3':
                List = 2 
                function.place() 
            elif act == 'play4':
                List = 3 
                function.place()
            elif act == 'play5':
                List = 4 
                function.place() 
    else: 
        pygame.draw.rect(window, ic, (x,y,width,height))      
    if msgColour == None:
        textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText, dark_grey)
    else:
        textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText, msgColour)
    textRect.center = ((x+(width/2)), (y+(height/2)))
    window.blit(textSurf, textRect)

class function():     
    def game(): 
        global win 
        global letters2 
        global Letters 
        global sen1 
        global sen2 
        global sen3 
        global sen4 
        global sen5 
        global sen6 
        global gameLoop 
        global wordLoop 
        global finalLoop 
        global number
        global sen
        global guesses
        words = ['ABOUT','ABOVE','ABUSE','AUDIO','BEGAN','BASIC','JAZZY','FIZZY','PIZZA','JAKEY','JERKY','CHIPS','CHEWS','CHOMP','CLEAN','DRYER','EIGHT','EQUAL','FLANK','STEAK','FLONG','FOOLS','FOOTY','GUARD'] 
        gameLoop = True 
        pygame.display.update() 
        window.blit(background, (0,0))
        word = []
        win = [] 
        randomWord = random.randint(0,13) 
        word.append(words[randomWord]) 
        letters = list(word[0]) 
        Letters = list(word[0])
        letters2 = []
        y = 0 
        for letter in letters: 
            y = y + 1 
        for letter in range(0,y): 
            letter = random.choice(letters) 
            letters.remove(letter) 
            letters2.append(letter) 
        sen = ['_ ' + '_ ' + '_ ' + '_ ' + '_ ', Letters[0] + ' _ ' + '_ ' + '_ ' + '_ ', Letters[0] + ' ' + Letters[1] + ' _ ' + '_ ' + '_ ',
                Letters[0] + ' ' + Letters[1] + ' ' + Letters[2] + ' _ ' + '_ ', Letters[0] + ' ' + Letters[1] + ' ' + Letters[2] + ' '+ Letters[3] + ' _ ',
                Letters[0] + ' ' + Letters[1] + ' ' + Letters[2] + ' '+ Letters[3] + ' ' + Letters[4]]
        gameLoop = True
        number = 0
        guesses = 5
        text.title(sen[number])
        while gameLoop: 
            if len(Letters) == 0: 
                finalLoop = True 
                while finalLoop: 
                    window.blit(background, (0,0))
                    text.title('YOU WIN!') 
                    button(550,500,250,100, rollover_menucolours, menucolours, 'Play Again', 'new', black, smallText) 
                    button(1250,500,250,100, rollover_menucolours, menucolours, 'Main Menu', 'menu', black, smallText) 
                    pygame.display.update()
                    for event in pygame.event.get():
                        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
                            pygame.quit() 

            elif guesses == 0:
                finalLoop = True 
                while finalLoop: 
                    window.blit(background, (0,0))
                    text.title('YOU LOSE')
                    button(550,500,250,100, rollover_menucolours, menucolours, 'Play Again', 'new', black, smallText) 
                    button(1250,500,250,100, rollover_menucolours, menucolours, 'Main Menu', 'menu', black, smallText) 
                    pygame.display.update() 

                    for event in pygame.event.get():
                        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 

                            pygame.quit() 

            button(width/2-220, height/2+50, 50, 50 ,rollover_menucolours, menucolours, letters2[0], 'play1', (black), smallText)
            button(width/2-120, height/2+50, 50, 50, rollover_menucolours, menucolours, letters2[1], 'play2', (black), smallText) 
            button(width/2-20, height/2+50, 50, 50, rollover_menucolours, menucolours, letters2[2], 'play3', (black), smallText) 
            button(width/2+70, height/2+50, 50, 50, rollover_menucolours, menucolours, letters2[3], 'play4', (black), smallText) 
            button(width/2+170, height/2+50, 50, 50, rollover_menucolours, menucolours, letters2[4], 'play5', (black), smallText) 
            pygame.display.update()



            for event in pygame.event.get(): 
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 

                    pygame.quit() 
    def menu(): 

        pygame.mixer.music.load("menu_music.mp3")
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
        mainLoop = True 
        clock.tick(1) 
        while mainLoop: 

            window.blit(background, (0,0)) 

            text.title('lettermatcher.edu') 

            button(550, 500, 250, 100, rollover_menucolours, menucolours, 'START', 'new', black, smallText) 
            button(900, 500, 250, 100, rollover_menucolours, menucolours, 'INSTRUCTIONS', 'rule', black, smallText) 
            button(1250, 500, 250, 100, rollover_menucolours, menucolours, 'QUIT', 'end', black, smallText)

            pygame.display.update() 

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    mainLoop = False 
                    pygame.quit() 
    def rules(): 
        global ruleLoop 
        ruleLoop = True
        while ruleLoop: 
            window.blit(background, (0,0)) 
            text.title('How to Play')
            text.display_message('The program will give you 5 letters', white, -50) 
            text.display_message('You have to click on the letters in order to create the word', white, 0) 
            text.display_message('If you pick the wrong letter five times you lose.', white, 50) 
            button(1550, 800, 250, 100, rollover_menucolours, menucolours, 'Main Menu', 'menu', black) 
            pygame.display.update() 

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:

                    pygame.quit()

    def place(): 
        global number
        global guesses
        if len(Letters) == 0:
                window.blit(background, (0,0)) 
                wordLoop = False 
                text.title('YOU WIN') 
                time.sleep(1) 
                ruleLoop = False
        elif letters2[List] == Letters[0]: 
            if len(Letters) == 5: 
                window.blit(background, (0,0))
                number += 1
                text.title(sen[number])
                Letters.remove(Letters[0])
            elif len(Letters) == 4: 
                window.blit(background, (0,0))
                number += 1
                text.title(sen[number])
                Letters.remove(Letters[0])
            elif len(Letters) == 3: 
                window.blit(background, (0,0))
                number += 1
                text.title(sen[number])
                Letters.remove(Letters[0]) 
            elif len(Letters) == 2:
                window.blit(background, (0,0))
                number += 1
                text.title(sen[number])
                Letters.remove(Letters[0])
            elif len(Letters) == 1: 
                window.blit(background, (0,0))
                number += 1
                text.title(sen[number])
                Letters.remove(Letters[0]) 
        elif letters2[List] not in Letters:
            time.sleep(0.1)
        else:
            guesses -= 1
            window.blit(background, (0,0))
            text.title(sen[number])
            gSen = 'Try again. you have ' + str(guesses) + ' left' 
            text.display_message(gSen, red)
            time.sleep(0.1)

    def end(): 
        pygame.quit() 

class text():

    def display_message(text, colour = None,y = None, x = None): 
        screenText = pygame.font.Font('FFFFORWA.ttf',25)
        if colour == None:
            textSurf, textRect = text_objects(text, screenText)
        else:
            textSurf, textRect = text_objects(text, screenText, colour)
        if y != None:
            if x != None:
                textRect.center = ((width/2+x),(height/2+y))
            else:
                textRect.center = ((width/2),(height/2+y))
        else:
            textRect.center = ((width/2),(height/2))
        window.blit(textSurf, textRect)

    def title(text):
        screenText = pygame.font.Font('FFFFORWA.ttf',80)
        textSurf, textRect = text_objects(text, screenText)
        textRect.center = ((960),(200))
        window.blit(textSurf, textRect)


function.menu()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is causes be the call of `pygame.quit()` in `end`:

> ```py
> def end(): 
>    pygame.quit()
> ```

Note, [`pygame.quit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.quit) uninitialize all pygame modules.

The real problem, however, is the design of your application. Every time when a button is clicked, then you step into the next function and level of the game. You never return from a function, you always get deeper and deeper on the call stack.
A button click event should not invoke a function directly. A button click changes a game state. The main application operates dependent on the game state and draw the scene dependent on the current state of the game.

Answer (score 0):

pygame.quit() doesn't quit the program but the display so the program continues to run and that creates a problem with the display.update(). What you should use is `sys.exit()` which would completely exit the program.

Comment: thanks it helps but it still, kind of crashes after i try and go back to the menu, i can still hear the sound but the game isnt responsive